# Compile types and pure functions between them (in ML-like or Haskell-like language) to SQL

Tags: sql, functional-programming, ml

Sometimes we need store binary tree or forest or set of data items of other algebraic type. It may be done some way. And it would be nice to perform some transformations on this data (rebalance binary tree, for example) also with SQL **only**.

I am interested in a way to declare types and pure functions between them (in ML-like or Haskell-like language) and compile them to SQL; I hope, it will allow me reuse code for standard algorithms such as hedge_union. Does it exists? May be, this compiler is implemented already (however I can't google it), or library in Coq exists, which can extract code in SQL, or something else.

Comment: 0_o ....SQL is not a compiled language.

Comment: @JackManey I want compile **to** sql -- de-facto, use advanced macros.

Comment: I don't know what that means, since there is no such thing as SQL compiled bytecode.

Comment: @JackManey Where is bytecode here? I want a simple tool: convert the source, written in some DSL with algebraic datatypes and pattern matchig, to the SQL (that is, it returns SQL code, a string containing SQL).

Comment: You can do this, but it depends greatly on the database that you are using. What database are you using?

Comment: @JackManey, I think he's looking to translate ML/Haskell functions into SQL. i.e., have a program take some functional language as input and produce SQL scripts as output.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Postresql is preferred.

Comment: I found an interesting paper.  Not sure if applies, but looks to be fit http://www.pllab.riec.tohoku.ac.jp/papers/icfp2011OhoriUenoAuthorVersion.pdf

Comment: @hydroparadise Thanks. Looks it does not answer my question, and it's very similar to urweb, but need be read more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

See e.g. recent research work on generating SQL from embedded functional languages, such as [Ferry](http://db.inf.uni-tuebingen.de/staticfiles/publications/ferryhaskell.pdf) — essentially typed, language-integrated queries.

See also: [Ferry — Database-Supported Program Execution](http://www-db.informatik.uni-tuebingen.de/projects/ferry.html) and [DSH — Database-Supported Haskell](http://www-db.informatik.uni-tuebingen.de/projects/databasesupportedhaskell.html).